# Routed event does not work

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and have a problem.
I want to handle a button event in its parent that is a grid element
but it does not show `ButtonBase.click` for me.
Can anyone tell me why?
Did I miss something?

this is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="CH01.CustomAttached.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CH01.CustomAttached"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

        <Button Content="Button" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it does not show ButtonBase.click_? `<Grid ButtonBase.Click="Button_Click">` does not work for you?

Comment: Ohh guys come on , it's my first question

Comment: yeah @dkozl  
the problem is there, it doesnt work 
Does it work for you?

Comment: Belive me, it does not do anything
Actually I just want to try routed events

Comment: @Siawash_s yes, what I've put in my comment works and triggers `Button_Click` on a `Grid` when `Button` is clicked

Comment: @dkozl :))) thanks man, it was a stupid question really